# RegEx to Remove Middle Initial in a Full Name

Tags: regex, lowercase, names

**Names for Example:** note there is no spaces.

JohnJSmith

MikeLJohnson

PeterWWalker

**result should be:**

JohnSmith

MikeJohnson

PeterWalker

[A-Z]{2} RegEx matches only two cap letters, not sure how to proceed from here.

Thankyou.

Comment: What happens with "ConanOBrien"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming,you have

1)Name starting with capital Letter followed by some small letters -> [A-Z][a-z]*

2)Capital Middle Letter-> [A-Z]

3)Capital Last Letter followed by some small letters -> [A-Z][a-z]*

U can split them into 3 groups

```
(^[A-Z][a-z]*)([A-Z])([A-Z][a-z]*)
```

**Since you need first and last group.You can get like this -> $1$3**

Eg.

```
'JohnJSmith'.replace(/(^[A-Z][a-z]*)([A-Z])([A-Z][a-z]*)/,'$1$3')->"JohnSmith"
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. Works like a charm.. Hopefully it will help other people as well. Your help is appreciated by many.  Thanks again.